# Google Chrome is crashing a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.03

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, crash

I recently installed Ubuntu version 14.04.3 on my desktop and I am experience chronic crashing/freezing of my computer while using Google Chrome (not Chromium). It most notably happens when I am listening to Youtube music and coding at the same time, but it also happens when I am just working on my web browser with anywhere between 3 - 20 tabs open.

When it freezes, I can still move my mouse and hear streaming audio, but I cannot click on anything (including non-chrome programs). My entire computer locks up and I have to do a hard restart on my PC.

Is this a common issue with this version of Ubuntu? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

May not be Chrome. Youtube crashing my browsers no matter what I am running. Might be an issue with adobe update but not sure.

Comment: It is definitely Chrome. I can do whatever I want in Firefox and it is fine. 
I need Chrome due to the killer web-dev tools.